# Bind multiple events at the same time (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I haven't used eventlisteners for very long and now I'm trying to use multiple eventlisteners (or one eventlistener for multiple events) and bind at the same time. It isn't going that well. One thing I'm trying to do is having two buttons point to different methods (this.a and this.b, see below) in the same object. I want the buttons to belong to the same form element in the HTML code. How would I go about this?

This is a simplified version of the code:

HTML

```
<form id="form">
    <div ID="buttons">
        <button id="buttonA" type="submit">A</button>
        <button id="buttonB" type="submit">B</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS (doesn't work)

```
var Example = function() {
    //properties
}

Example.prototype.a = function() {
    document.querySelector("#buttonA").removeEventListener("submit", this.methodA);
    // do stuff
}

Example.prototype.b = function() {
    document.querySelector("#buttonB").removeEventListener("submit", this.methodB);
    // do stuff
}

Example.prototype.decision = function() {
    this.methodA = this.a.bind(this);
    this.methodB = this.b.bind(this);

    document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    });

    document.querySelector("#buttonA").addEventListener("submit", this.methodA, false);
    document.querySelector("#buttonB").addEventListener("submit", this.methodB, false);
}
```

As you can see, the code is a mess right now. And even if it did work (which it doesn't), I'm not sure this is the best way to do it because I have to listen on the buttons separately (ideally, I think, you would only have to listen on #form).

What would be a proper and working solution?

Btw, method a and b are sort of like previous "states" in the program that the user can return to by clicking the buttons.

Comment: if code is working correctly and need some improvement , than you can try posting it in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _"What would be a proper and working solution?"_  What _actual_ problem are you trying to solve - this really looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What exactly you want  ?

Comment: There are no submit events on buttons.

Comment: @n01ze: No, this code doesn't work at all.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: This could be an "XY" type of situation, yes. I felt I had to show my current "solution" in order to illustrate the problem and what I'm trying to do (and that I have in fact tried), but it's probably very far from a working solution. I'm just looking for a (good) way to bind multiple events at the same time and jumping from one method to one of two other methods based on what button is clicked.

Comment: @Musa: Oh, okay. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Handle click event on the form instead, and in that handle decide according to target property of the event which function to call next:

```js
var Example = function() {
    this.testA = "AAA";
    this.testB = "BBB";
}

Example.prototype.a = function() {
    alert(this.testA);
}

Example.prototype.b = function() {
    alert(this.testB);
}

var exam = new Example();

document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    switch(event.target.id) {
     case "buttonA":
       exam.a.apply(exam);
        exam.a();
       break;
   case "buttonB":
       exam.b.apply(exam);
        exam.b();
       break;        
     default:
       break;
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <div ID="buttons">
        <button id="buttonA" type="submit">A</button>
        <button id="buttonB" type="submit">B</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the bind/this problem though, does it? How would you work bind into this?

Comment: You can call your methods within any scope you want, using "call" or "apply". This is solution for your problem (as I see it) to have one event handler for multiple buttons. Inside that handler you can call any function you want. Did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: No, probably not, it's just that I haven't done this before and am somewhat confused/tired =) I thought you needed to use bind so that 'this' points to the correct function. I have managed to use bind when there is just one function but here we have two functions and two buttons. Is it even possible to use bind in this situation? In any case, I will try to work with your solution as well ...

Comment: So what does the bind? "...The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value...". There is no need to create new function, but you can use it, as you can use "apply" or "call"

Comment: I updated my post, as you can see, in this use there is no need to use event apply, neither bind.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it could work... maybe? It's just that in your example the eventlistener is external from the exam object, in my case it's internal. In my case, the eventlistener is inside a method and where you use exam.a and exam.b I need to use this.a and this.b in order to reference the same methods. That's why I wanted to use bind with the eventlistener.

Comment: document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("click", exam.a.bind(exam))

Comment: That's not too far from how I did it in the OP. But here you still have to add two separate eventlisteners for a and b, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Obviously you do not see the point. There is one event handler. Not two. And I gave you example how to call from it two separate methods, these methods are not event handlers. Use it, or throw it.